# Biderictionnal relationship create double object (HIbernate)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

first of all it is not a duplicate question. So, here is my question. I got a biderictionnal relationship. So here are my two entities. The first one is **Company.java**:

```
public class Company implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
....
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="company",cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Contract> contracts;
```

}

And the other entity is **Contract.java**:

```
public class Contract implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Company company;
```

}

So my problem is that when I create a **Contract** and add it to my **Contracts** I constate that in my database tables that I got two elements in my table **Contract**, I would like to got only one element who is **Contract**. Is that possible, thank you.

Comment: Whether it is a duplicate or not is for others to define, not you. If you have a problem with what gets persisted, why not post the actual persistence code that leads to such objects in the database?!

Comment: Do you set the company for the contract that you add?
can you post the two rows that get persisted ?
can you post the code where you add the contract to the company and the code of persisting ?

Comment: @osama I think it is normal that I got two objects created because I do this in my code, company.getContracts().add(relatedContract) and the **relatedContract** is a new contract. But I want to do is this company.getContracts().add(existingContract) and there I got error telling me : detached object.

Comment: This is something different than the topic question if I understand well , correct ?

Comment: So go back to my comment #1 ... `post the actual persistence code that leads to such objects in the database` ... in your QUESTION